# flutterfire configure not working even after installing via npm, and relogging

Tags: flutter, firebase, command-line-interface

I keep getting this error no matter what I attempt to do,

I've already tried using "npm install -g firebase-tools",
and "firebase projects:list" displays a correct list of my current projects.

Looking for help as I have sunk countless hours into this problem without being able to move a step forward.

````
   FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the 
   Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
   COMMAND: firebase --version
   ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it. ```
````

Answer (score 2):

In case you have installed (and renamed) `firebase.exe` from the windows installer, remove that first.

The installation of `npm install -g firebase-tools` and the windows installer are conflicting with each other.

Then go through `firebase logout` and `firebase login` again before running `flutterfire configure`.

Comment: I just finished doing that, still `firebase configure` is not working. Could this have anything to do with `firebase init`?

Comment: Create a project with 'flutter create test'. Go inside `test` and `flutter pub add firebase_core`. Then `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`. Then `flutterfire configure`. Also, make sure that `firebase.exe` is nowhere in your PATH.

Comment: Alright, so I created a new project, added firebase_core dependency and run the `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`. Everything is fine until this point, but running `flutterfire configure` after this invokes the same error as the one originally in the post. My path looks like this: `C:\Users\USER\test`. No `firebase.exe` in it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mh, at this point I would invole  `firebase login` and then `firebase init`. Then try again with `flutterfire configure`. Normally, Flutterfire should do the init itself, as I understand it.

Comment: same problem even after running `firebase login` and `firebase init`, its not working :(

Comment: Mh, is there an error or debug log like 'firebase-debug.log` generated by Flutterfire? Also, make sure that the user-email accessing the Firebase Web Console is the same email used when doing `firebase login`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245304/discussion-between-thesadoun1996-and-dabbel).

Answer (score 1):

I added the firebase-tools file downloaded from  https://firebase.tools/bin/win/instant/latest in the root of the directory of my project and it works for me. I changed the name to firebase only.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me

```
curl -sL firebase.tools | upgrade=true bash
```